# How to remove data points that don't overlap with other data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am working with a dataset for the whole state, but I want only the data point that overlap with another polygon dataset. How do I get rid of the excess points that don't overlap?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you seek the [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) tool.